# Why isn't my Sublime Text 3 editor colourful?

Tags: text, colors, tags, editor

In all the guides and setup tutorials on the internet people's Sublime Text editors are colourful like this:

[image]

Why is mine plain like this?:

[image]

Comment: You need to configure the syntax highlighting. You can google various instructions.

Comment: Your file has no extention. You should rename it to `testing.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublime should have HTML built-in - you should be able to just do CMD+Shift+P and type 'HTML', and set the syntax to HTML.

It will default to this syntax if you're editing a `.html` file, but if you're starting from a new file you'll need to set it to that or save it as that format for Sublime to recognize it.

If not (or if you need any other packages), install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/), then use that to install packages for different languages.

Comment: it works now I that I have saved the file as filename.html instead of 'saving asing' as .html format.